# Убрать сколонение месяцев в значениях осей графика Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Необходимо отобразить названия месяцев на оси х графика на русском языке.
Делаю так:

```
import datetime
import locale
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dates = [
    datetime.date(2021, 10, 21),
    datetime.date(2021, 8, 25),
]
y = [0, 1]
plt.plot_date(dates, y)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl_dates.MonthLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%B'))
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8")
plt.show()
```

И получаю в подписях к графику названия месяцев на русском языке, но в родительном падеже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить названия месяцев в именительном падеже?

PS. Пробовал ещё получать названия месяцев через pandas:

```
dt.month_name(locale="ru_RU.utf8")
```

Но результат тот же. Видимо механизм одинаковый.

Comment: Windows 10, pycharm, Matplotlib 3.7.1 - именительный падеж.

Comment: Linux, Ubuntu 22.04, Matplotlib 3.7.3

Comment: Родительный падеж

Comment: Не, это же линукс. Тут такой локали и нет

Comment: Так-то ОС у вас более правильно переводит 25 сентября. Можно использовать сокращенное название месяцев `mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%b')`

Comment: Да, если надо 25 сентября, то работает. С сокращением тоже работает. Но именно сейчас требуется полное наименование месяца и в именительном падеже. Может всё-таки как-то можно получить?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать свой "переводчик", используя функцию `FuncFormatter` для форматирования даты меток тикеров. При этом убираем немного костыльный метод `locale.setlocale` и  устаревающий `plt.plot_date`, см. [док.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date.html)

> Этот метод существует по историческим причинам и в будущем будет устаревшим.
>
> `datetime`-подобные данные должны быть непосредственно отображены с
> использованием `plot`.
>
> Если вам нужно отобразить простые числовые данные в формате даты
> Matplotlib или установить часовой пояс, вызовите `ax.xaxis.axis_date/`
> `ax.yaxis.axis_date` перед построением графика. См. `Axis.axis_date`.

```
import datetime
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# Создаем словарь месяцев анг-рус.
months_en = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
months_ru = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь']
months = dict(zip(months_en, months_ru))

dates = [
    datetime.date(2021, 10, 21),
    datetime.date(2021, 8, 25),
]
y = [0, 1]

month_fmt = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%B')
def month(x, pos):
    # Заменяем английское наименование месяца на русское.
    return months[month_fmt(x)]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(dates, y)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl_dates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(month))

plt.show()
```